# Android React-Native - Text textDecorationLine style doesn't work

Tags: android, react-native

For Android platform, is there anyway to decorate < Text >, for example, I want to be able to add border styles (like in < Image >) or at the very least ability to underline on touch..
Tried this below code and it doesn't work

```
style={{textDecorationLine: 'underline', textDecorationStyle: 'dotted', textDecorationColor: 'blue'}}>
```

Looks like this is being tracked https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3819

Looking for ways to decorate `<Text>` until this gets fixed.

Thanks !

Comment: I think the next step is to log an issue and reference it in product pains.  We can then vote on it there.

Comment: It looks like we are close: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5105 thanks to Maxi Ferreira.

Comment: The PR referenced above resolved this issue